# How to integrate two react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two created applications. Both applications are standalone applications deployed separately. Application A (runs on localhost:9000) backend is scala and application B (runs on localhost:9003) is nodejs. The front end of both applications is reactjs. Now the application A has to show application B UI in one of its tabs.

To achieve this I did window.location.href when someone clicks on that tab. It works.

But can there be a way where if I click on the tab it shouldn't change/redirect the URL? So if I hit localhost:9000 and when clicked on the tab URL will become localhost:9003.

Instead of changing href I can use the `iframe` and load the other application(localhost:9003) in `iframe`. This way URL (localhost:9000) wouldn't change. It will look like it's part of the application. What else could be done?

Comment: will you merge 2 applications into one in the final Production Stage?

Comment: there are tons of different solutions out there. The term you are looking for is `Micro frontend`. I've written a beginner's guide on how to achieve that with webpack, maybe you can take a look https://medium.com/paloit/a-beginners-guide-to-micro-frontends-with-webpack-module-federation-712f3855f813

Comment: Nice article, @Isaac.